# Snowflake SQL - compare two tables in two tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables with the same column names and want the query to return row values in one table that has no match in the other.

both tables TABLE_1 AND TABLE_2  have these two columns only:  employee_id, work_tenure

this is my query -  and **even though I see differences** the end result shows empty:

```
select * from (

  (select employee_id, work_tenure from table_1  group by 1,2)
   union
  (select employee_id, work_tenure from table_1  group by 1,2)
)
group by employee_id, work_tenure
having count(*) > 1
order by employee_id, work_tenure
;
```

How do I fix the query above?

Comment: Check out the [set operators](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query) documentation. You are likely wanting `MINUS` or its synonym `EXCEPT` instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should do a full outer join to have better visibility into which table is missing what. If all you care about is what's missing, here is a set-based approach

```
(select 'missing_in_t2', * 
 from t1
 except --to just see what's missing in t2
 select 'missing_in_t2', * 
 from t2)

union all -- to combine what's missing in either of the tables

(select 'missing_in_t1', * 
 from t2
 except --to just see what's missing in t1
 select 'missing_in_t1', * 
 from t1)
```

It's not the most performant solution, but the syntax is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: thank you very much, this query does work.
Just one additional question - wondering how do I  edit the query to also display the table name  (table_1  or table_2) in the difference result?

Comment: just change the 1st line as `(select 'table 1`, * from t1 and 5th line as `(select 'table 2', * from t2`

Comment: @punsoca See my edits if you still need help

Answer (score 1):

To make your SQL work, first I have to assume the second table of the UNION is meant to be table_2, thus:

```
select * from (
   select employee_id, work_tenure from table_1 group by 1,2
   union
   select employee_id, work_tenure from table_2 group by 1,2
)
group by employee_id, work_tenure
having count(*) > 1
order by employee_id, work_tenure;
```

Then if we swap to a `UNION ALL` which does a "just take all the rows together" which is what you seems to want, where-as `UNION` only takes the distinct, thus your code will have no rows with double counts.

And if you are wanting the rows in ether you want the `count(*) = 1` as compared to `> 1` as that will just be rows in both.

so your code should be:

```
select * from (
  select employee_id, work_tenure from table_1  group by 1,2
   union ALL
  select employee_id, work_tenure from table_2  group by 1,2
)
group by employee_id, work_tenure
having count(*) = 1
order by employee_id, work_tenure;
```

now if we make-up some data (I am using a CTE):

```
with table_1(employee_id, work_tenure) as (
    select * from values 
    (1,10),
    (2,20)
), table_2(employee_id, work_tenure) as (
    select * from values 
    (2,20),
    (3,30)
)
```

we can see the 2,20 is in both sets, so we want "the other rows" giving:

[image]

### Union ALL vs Union:

because the UNION ALL includes all the rows:

[image]

where-as UNION removes the duplicates:

[image]

### Minus:

[MINUS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query#minus-except) does the lot of this for you thus, and as Radagast notes to have to do it in both directions.